# Fatwire Content Server Explorer on OSX

Tags: macos, explorer, fatwire

Is there a FatWire Content Server Solution Explorer for OSX? I'm currently on an XP machine running Content Server Explorer 7.5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Content Server Explorer is a Windows only product, but it can be run easily on Linux distributions such as Ubuntu with the latest version of Wine. You therefore might want to consider using Darwine for OSX.

When using Wine under Ubuntu for CSE, you need to make sure that the "wininet" library is set to load as a Native (Windows) library, not the Wine version (which is the default); check the Win Configuration dialog, then create a new profile for CSE.exe and set the Windows version to 'Use global settings', then add the wininet library preference in the Libraries tab.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have just been using the updating the content through the browser.